# Problems installing Api.ai into xamarin

Tags: xamarin, dialogflow-es

i keep having this error when trying to install dialog flow (API.AI) into my xamarin 
       Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'ApiAi 1.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Version 1 of the API.AI are legacy and will be disabled in less then 12 months, you should be using V2 : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2

Comment: Alright thank you... Would try that

Comment: I have done the installation...but cannot load the classes..the tutorial i am following is at https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-xamarin-client/blob/master/ApiAiSDK/component/GettingStarted.md ...Please help.. I am new at this @sushiHangover